# Why is the fillable form I created in Word 2007 skipping from page 1 to the last page?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, forms

I created a 4 page fillable form and locked it for users to complete and send back to me. When a user opens the form they can tab through the first page fine, but when you hit tab to go to the next field on the next page it skips to the top of the last page. If you scroll up and place your cursor in the first field of the 2nd page it will then let you tab through the rest of the document fine. I've searched for a possible answer to why it's doing this to no avail. Any help you could provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: which types of form fields are you using?

Comment: Does it work for you (as if you were completing the form like those who you are sending it to)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are dealing with the fact that Word decides the tab order of the fields automatically. There isn't much you can do about it from the standard interface, but here is an MVP article with a way to work around it.

[How to set the “tab order” of a Word form](http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/SetTabOrder.htm)

Comment: +1 was surprised this is the behavior, but many articles verify this is the case.

Comment: I am using Legacy form fields. It does the same thing for me when I open the form. My boss wanted me to add some revisions. It was after that when it started doing this. The older version of the form does not do that. He wanted the Name field to automatically populate on pages 2-4 after the user fills in their name on page 1. I put a styleref in the header but had to insert a continuous page break so it would not appear on page 1. I thought that is what caused it but when I deleted the break it continues to skip. I don't want to use macros if I can help it. I've never used userforms. Thanks!!!